# Date column in delete statement along with the index column

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

Need help on below issue.

I need to delete rows from a table having huge amount of data getting inserted on daily basis, I have written a procedure which deletes the rows based on a column having index on it which to me should be enough but my collegue suggested me to use a date column as well to delete the data as this will use date parition (Parition is based on date).

My doubt is which delete statement would be faster to delete the data.

E.g

```
1. Column name :- FILE_NAME (Having index)
            delete from table_name where column_name1=file_name
2. Column name1 :- FILE_NAME (HHaving index) and column name2:- TXN_DATE (no index, Partition is on this column)
            delete from table_name where column_name1=file_name and txn_date=date_value
```

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Well have you run explain plan and tkprof on the statements to see the actual profile?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your colleague is right. The second query will be quicker.

The process is called `partition pruning`. Using the column, based on which partitions are created will automatically hit only the necessary partitions where the data is available.

You can also directly reference the partition if you can determine the name of the partition for the date_value, as

```
DELETE FROM table_name 
PARTITION (partition_date_value) 
WHERE column_name1=file_name;
```

**References**:

[Examples for DELETE  on Oracle Database SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_8005.htm#i2143613)

[Partition Pruning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c12parti.htm#459933)

[Another Partition Pruning website](http://www.orafaq.com/tuningguide/partition%20prune.html)

Answer (score 0):

If file name is a index that actually improves the navigation on your table, i think it would be faster to use the first one.